# How to extract a zip file and render the contents, client side

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, zip

I have a zip file located at `http://my-website.com/user-site.zip`. This zip file contains a bunch of html, css and javascript files that, when extracted, look something like this (exact contents unknown):

```
index.html
js/
  script.js
css/
  style.css
```

I want to be able to view this webpage in, e.g., an iframe, after downloading it in-browser.

Right now my approach looks like this:

1. Download the zip file from the server.
2. Use [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to extract the files in-memory.
3. Use `createObjectUrl` (explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images)) to create urls for each of these assets.
4. Point the iframe to the url generated by `index.html`.

This *almost* works, except for one problem. *The urls generated by `createObjectUrl` are pretty much random, so `index.html` can't resolve references to other resources.* How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Very great question! I'm sitting here pondering this myself now! One thing that you could do is create a JavaScript object/array to "map" the files and their paths, along with their created object URLs. Then use JavaScript to replace the relative paths with the absolute object URLs. Unless...you can't get the path of the file.

If that is the case, a JavaScript library you may be interested in would be [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), which can give you paths for files within a ZIP.

[image: JSZip Example]

For your map, you could do something like this (after you strip necessary parts from the JSZip path like the root directory):

```
var map = [
    {"relativePath":"css.css","absolutePath":*Object URL Goes Here*}
];
```

Then loop through each entry in the map and replace every instance of relativePath[x] with the absolutePath[x] in a given file, whether it be the raw text of the file or the innerHTML of the iframe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is useful, thanks Ricky! You can also create a map by (1) iterate through each file in the zip with `zip.js` or any zip library, (2) call `createObjectURL` on each file in the zip, and (3) add that to a mapping object (e.g., `map[localUrl] = globalUrl`).

Comment: So the problem I'm facing has to do more with *routing* those URLs, once you've generated them. In other words, let's say I can reference a bunch of files by url. Great. Now, *how do I render them in a page*? I would love to be able to point an iframe to the global url of `index.html`, but that won't work for reasons explained above.

Comment: Rendering? If I'm catching your drift, couldn't you just get the contents of "index.html",  replace your URLs from that string, then use document.write() to write the string to the iframe's contentDocument?

Comment: That's a good idea, and I think it would work in most cases. But what if the local url (e.g., `script.js`) appears multiple times in the file? Or what if they use some linking mechanism that loads a (locally-stored) file in over xhr? In these cases simply replacing the string `script.js` with `global_file_url/script.js` would not work. Ultimately we need to find a more robust way of dynamically routing urls.

Comment: Using Regular Expressions, you can replace every occurrence of a string. What do you mean by local? Outside the ZIP and still on the computer?

Comment: Yep! I'm saying that regex isn't robust enough to cover all the different ways to fetch a resource.

Comment: Well that's true. But then again, no RegExp is perfect. You'd have a 98% success rate or higher. Just never 100% sadly. As for files outside the ZIP, if you were referencing a file that's in "My Documents" (Windows), you'd need to know the current user's username because of the filepath, which I don't think you can determine through JavaScript.

Comment: To be honest replacing internal urls with global urls using regex is kind of a hack. There should be a way to actually perform this routing on a deeper level - look at what Angular does in `ui-router`.

Comment: By the way I really appreciate your effort in answering this question.